# How is it possible to have more then 1 concurrent connection in IIS?

Tags: iis, concurrency, stateless

From what I understand about the HTTP protocol is that it is stateless. This means (to me) that is, it is only ever serving one connection at a time.

Even if there is 1,000,000 million users trying to access a site, it can only ever be serving one connection at a time.

So when I see a setting in IIS saying "Maximum number of concurrent users" (or similar) it makes me wonder, what does this mean?

Comment: Stateless does not mean a lack of concurrency.  Those are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, it can be any number until the TCP connections run out.

In reality, it is limited by your hardware and your applications and what the application/users are doing. You need to do stress test for your server.

hope it help.